# Can two automated systems "interface" between each other?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to indicate unlimited interaction between two applications.

Would the following work?

> Our developer API allows you to interface with [product] without limitation!

Comment: Your example seems fine (grammatically) as Dale says. The title of your question, however, is entirely different. In the example, *you* are interfacing, and you’re doing it *with* something; in the title, two systems are interfacing, and they’re doing it *between* each other. That makes no sense. You can’t interface between something, only with something.

Comment: Use 'with', not 'between'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English construction seems perfectly acceptable, however, the substance of what you are saying seems problematical.

"without limitation" means that I can interface in any way or method that I choose; yet I must use your API which is a limitation. In addition, it is probable that there will be a limited number of functions that your API provides; another limitation. I think you need to be more specific about exactly what is "without limitation"

Comment: I wouldn’t really say that having to use an API is a limitation to interfacing with a system. ‘Interface’ as a verb means exactly to connect to a different machine/system/etc. _via an interface_, so that’s a limitation inherent in interfacing, rather than a limitation imposed on interfacing. Your second point I agree with (presuming that this isn’t an API that simply enables full access to interface with [product] without any limitations whatsoever, of course).

Comment: Maybe you might say something like "with large flexibility" instead of "without limitation", so that it does not sound as a marketing...

Comment: Your API provides access to the complete interface.

Comment: @Pam, the phrasing and content make it very likely that this _is_ marketing.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a word such as connect, interact, or engage. Your usage above is definitely grammatically correct, but without researching the word 'interface' I assumed it was wrong. Most people, if not all, will assume interface refers to a GUI or something similar.

Comment: APIs do not generally access GUIs—they interface with systems, kernels, cores, etc. The verb used is entirely idiomatic.

Comment: The example sentence appears to be targeted at software developers who would not be confused by the multiple sub-meanings of "interface".

Answer (score 0):

> Our developer API allows you to interface with [product] without constraint.

Use the term *constraint*. It is an industry-standard term, when it comes to having no limitation placed on it by the system, though there certainly would be limitations to the capability of the software, the system and the legal liability on the part of the user from using it to harm others.

In dispute to Johndubstep5's opinion, *interface* is an acceptable word to use here. In software engineering, there are a few variant uses of the term interface, for example,

- the user-system interface either graphical (GUI) or teletype (tty)
- pointer device (mouse, pad) interfaces
- API-to-API Interface, aka API-contract (the Java/C# Interface)